# What are the steps in resolving a DLL "could not resolve reference" issues

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dll, tfs

I have a sln. file builds and runs on local machine.  When I get to the point of building the sln in the TFS server I get an error

> Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "DataTables"(assembly I am referring to). Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

I have attempted to step through the process of troubleshooting this error, here is what I have done so far:

- Made sure the target framework is the same on both
- Made sure to have a static dll file location
- Made sure to reference the file in the sln and use the accompanying using statements

What would be the next logical area to look into?

I think the problem resides in that the first time I referenced the dll it was in one location and I changed the dll file location a few times before where it is now because I stored the dll in the desktop and had to reorganize my folders.

I briefly read somewhere that when the local build is able to run, it could be that the sln file has the original dll saved to the bin and uses that copy when it cannot find the dll in the file location listed in the references section.

I can connect the two ideas together but I don't know how to get the sln file to remove traces of the no longer valid dll file location and make it start to use the correct dll file path.

I could be wrong and there may be a different problem source that I have over looked.

I am a beginner so be aware there may be misconceptions and I may have slaughtered a few concepts in the section above.  Any insights and advise would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had someone help me build the sln.  these are the steps we used to change the file reference and allow it to work.
We dropped the dll into the sln file and then we changed the reference hint by unloading the project and then right click "edit" sln.

In that interface we changed the xml file and changed the reference to within the sln and it now builds in the prod. server

Thanks ! Hope this helps someone else.

P.S. I would still like some clarification of what went wrong (e.g. was the hint file path to long, and/or what could I have done to make the reference work without having to move the dll into the sln file in case that is not an option in another time this issue occurs.

Comment: Unless you use MSBuild diagnostics logging to collect more data about the resolution process, nobody would magically see your code and show you why.

Answer (score 0):

This is why, the hint path was referencing the file to a path that was outside of source control so when the build server pulled the code it couldn't resolve the dll at C:\users[name]\desktop\ (or wherever it was referenced from at that point) on the BUILD server.

"I think the problem resides in that the first time I referenced the dll it was in one location and I changed the dll file location a few times before where it is now because I stored the dll in the desktop and had to reorganize my folders."

Comment: I see, thanks! I was really stumped on this one.  What really tripped me up was that I had dragged and dropped the dll file into the same folder as where the sln was. I had assumed that the build server would detect the file and pick it up from the folder.  This was a character building bug/trouble shoot, I came out of this one knowing more about how a sln directory works and what the bin file holds, etc. Life is the Journey

Comment: I see people do this all the time. The big thing to remember is that only files located under the SourceControlFolder from the build definition are pulled into the build so anything referenced to something not under that root will not be present in the build. GAC references are ok (if same ones are installed on the server) but anything else has to be under there and referenced with a relative hint path.